# Java store values in map

Tags: java

Let class getChoice implement a LinkedHashMap.
Let a method addCh implement the choice.put.
Let some classes choice1 and choice2 extend class choice and passing elements to getChoice.map. Each time I'm passing an object to Map it seems not to update but rather to be created again with the same name. I need to store all elements first in map and then save them into a file. How can I do that? My code so far.

```
public class GetChoice{

Map<String, String> choice = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

public void addChoice(SomeClass obj1, SomeOtherClass obj2) {

    if (obj2 instanceof Choice1) {
        this.choice.put(obj2.toString(), "choice1");
    } else if (obj2 instanceof Choice2) {
        this.choice.put(obj2.toString(), "choice2");
    } else {
        //sysout not found
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + choice);
}
```

**Edit**: I handled it by declaring the Map as static, after @dasblinkenlight mentioned it is created each call.
Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you are trying to do.  Can you give an example of how you want to use the `GetChoice` class and what you expect the results to be?

Comment: Please show the code where you call `new GetChoice()`. I pretend in my answer that I know that you do it each time you call `addChoice`, because this is the only reasonable explanation of the behavior that you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`choice` map is an instance field of the `GetChoice` object. Every time you make a new `GetChoice` a brand-new map with no data is created.

In order to persist the data in the map across invocations of `addChoice` you need to create your `GetChoice` object once, and then call `addChoice` on that same object multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

> ***it seems not to update but rather to be created again with the same name***

for sure your parameters are crossed-over so you are using as Key the 
**obj2**

for example:
 doing this:

```
addChoice(1, 11);
addChoice(2, 3.14);
addChoice(3, 45);
addChoice(1111, 45);
addChoice(111111, 45);
addChoice(1234, 45);
```

will produce  **3 elements** in the list... 11, pi, and 45, no matter how many 
different kind of **obj1** you use..